# How to define callable attribute with covariant return type on protocol?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Usually it is understood that the return type of a callable is *co*variant.  When defining a type with a callable *attribute*, I can indeed make the return type generic and covariant:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Generic, Sequence
from dataclasses import dataclass

R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)

@dataclass
class Works(Generic[R]):
    call: Callable[[], R]  # returns an R *or subtype*

w: Works[Sequence] = Works(lambda: [])  # okay: list is subtype of Sequence
```

However, the same does not work for a `Protocol`. When I define a `Protocol` for the type in the same way, MyPy rejects this – it insists the return type must be *in*variant.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Protocol

R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)

class Fails(Protocol[R]):
    attribute: Callable[[], R]
```

```sh
$ python -m mypy so_testbed.py --pretty
so_testbed.py:5: error: Covariant type variable "R" used in protocol where invariant one is expected
    class Fails(Protocol[R]):
    ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I properly define a `Protocol` for the concrete type that respects the covariance of `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're attempting is explicitly not possible with `Protocol` - see the following in [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-attributes):

---

> **Covariant subtyping of mutable attributes**
>
> Rejected because covariant
> subtyping of mutable attributes is not safe. Consider this example:

```
class P(Protocol):
    x: float

def f(arg: P) -> None:
    arg.x = 0.42

class C:
    x: int

c = C()
f(c)  # Would typecheck if covariant subtyping
      # of mutable attributes were allowed.
c.x >> 1  # But this fails at runtime
```

> It was initially proposed to allow this for practical reasons, but it
> was subsequently rejected, since this may mask some hard to spot bugs.

---

Since your `attribute` is a mutable member - you cannot have it be covariant with regards to `R`.

A possible alternative is to replace `attribute` with a method:

```
class Passes(Protocol[R]):
    @property
    def attribute(self) -> Callable[[], R]:
        pass
```

which passes type-checking - but it's an inflexible solution.

If you have need of mutable covariant members, `Protocol` isn't the way to go.

Comment: "A possible alternative is to replace attribute with a method:" Good idea. Adding an ``@property`` makes the method a write-only attribute, which matches the use case even better.

Comment: Could you add the ``@property`` to your final code block? That's the variant I've picked for my real code and it matches the expectation best – would accept that solution.

Comment: Sure, added :) it's a nice improvement

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel Kleinstein pointed out, you cannot parameterize the protocol type by a covariant variable because it is used for a mutable attribute.

Another alternative is to split the variables into two (covariant and invariant) and use them in two protocols ([replace](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) `Callable` with `Protocol`).

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Protocol

R_cov = TypeVar("R_cov", covariant=True)
R_inv = TypeVar("R_inv")

class CallProto(Protocol[R_cov]):
    def __call__(self) -> R_cov: ...
    
class Fails(Protocol[R_inv]):
    attribute: CallProto[R_inv]
```